# rails 3.2 rails generate rspec:install... undefined method `delegate_template_exists?' for class `ActionView::Base' (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, haml, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Got this error trying to do a new project with rails 3.2.
haml issue ?

```
rails generate rspec:install
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/haml-3.1.3/lib/haml/template/patch.rb:16:  
in `alias_method': undefined method `delegate_template_exists?'  
for class `ActionView::Base' (NameError)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1321) reported to rails. There was some discussion both in Rails and HAML and looks like it was fixed [there](https://github.com/nex3/haml/pull/398). Try using HAML `3.1.4`.